# Kendo Grid. I want to show all active organizations when checkbox is checked.

Tags: kendo-grid

I want to show all active organizations when toolbar check-box is checked. I have added a check-box in kendo grid toolbar but unable to perform the desired task. I have attached an image so you can better understand my problem. please help

[Kendo Grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WX87b.png)

Comment: try adding a filter to the grid datasource. dataSource.filter( { field: "organization", operator: "active", value: "true" });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this also,

```
$('#ShowActiveOrganization').on('change',function(e){
   var $grid = $("#organizationGrid").data("kendoGrid");
   var $checkBox=$(this);
   $grid.dataSource.filter({ "field": "status", "operator": "eq", "value":  checkBox.is(':checked') })
}):
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your grid in html looks like this

```
<div id="organizationGrid"></div>
```

now just write this line on your check box's change event

```
var grid = $("#organizationGrid").data("kendoGrid");
grid.dataSource.filter({ "field": "status", "operator": "eq", "value": true });
```

Above code will filter your grid dataSource based on "Status" field.

Please next time use jsbin or any online code editor to give example, so you can get answers in "LIVE" view, instead of this virtual code.

:)